# What book are the bloodvelds from?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, dnd-3e, product-identification

Our DM and the other DM in our party distinctly recall seeing a creature called a "bloodveld" in a D&D 3.5e book.  This creature is a colorless aquatic ooze that feeds on the blood of whatever it attacks, and is nearly invisible when in the water.  However, *nobody* in our group can find it in any of their books, and all our Googling comes up with references to Runescape(!?).  Just *where* was the statblock for this creature published?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you might be thinking of the **Bloodbloater**.

It's an aquatic ooze that seems to fit your description perfectly.

If so, it can be found in the **3e Fiend Folio** under "aquatic ooze".